# How to change the image of an ImageView when clicked?

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

This is my code. I'm a beginner to this, but I need to do it quickly. Using an ImageView's onClick, how do I check if the image it is displaying is equal to a drawable and how do I change the image that the ImageVIew is displaying?

My code so far

```
public void grid1Click(View view) {
    if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid1)).getDrawable().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.grid)))
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid1)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gridfilled));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
ImageView imageViwe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_id);
imageViwe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Set new image to imageview here

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I can now switch the image, but how do I check if the imageView's drawable is equal to a drawable?

Comment: You can check it by like : `if(background instanceof GradientDrawable)` or somethinf like this , And please mark the question as the correct answer :)